# How do I chain methods in PHP?

Tags: php, methods, method-chaining

jQuery lets me chain methods. I also remember seeing the same in PHP so I wrote this:

```
class cat {
 function meow() {
 echo "meow!";
 }

function purr() {
 echo "purr!";
 }
}

$kitty = new cat;

$kitty->meow()->purr();
```

I cannot get the chain to work. It generates a fatal error right after the meow.

Comment: The example with kitty is much more illustrative ;-)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

To answer your cat example, your cat's methods need to return `$this`, which is the current object instance. Then you can chain your methods:

```
class cat {
 function meow() {
  echo "meow!";
  return $this;
 }

 function purr() {
  echo "purr!";
  return $this;
 }
}
```

Now you can do:

```
$kitty = new cat;
$kitty->meow()->purr();
```

For a really helpful article on the topic, see here: http://www.talkphp.com/advanced-php-programming/1163-php5-method-chaining.html

Comment: Article gone. Here is [the last working archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20130417023845/http://www.talkphp.com/advanced-php-programming/1163-php5-method-chaining.html).

Answer (score 7):

Place the following at the end of each method you wish to make "chainable":

```
return $this;
```

Answer (score 4):

Just return `$this` from your method, i.e. (a reference to) the object itself:

```
class Foo()
{
  function f()
  {
    // ...
    return $this;
  }
}
```

Now you can chain at heart's content:

```
$x = new Foo;
$x->f()->f()->f();
```

Answer (score 2):

yes using php 5 you can return object from a method. So by returning `$this` (which points to the current object), you can achieve method chaining

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Same answer as the rest of them...