# Building chained function calls dynamically in PHP

Tags: php, function, object, dynamically-generated, kirby

I use PHP (with KirbyCMS) and can create this code:

```
$results = $site->filterBy('a_key', 'a_value')->filterBy('a_key2', 'a_value2');
```

This is a chain with two `filterBy`. It works.

However I need to build a function call like this dynamically. Sometimes it can be two chained function calls, sometimes three or more.

How is that done?

**Maybe you can play with this code?**

chain is just a random number that can be used to create between 1-5 chains.

```
for( $i = 0; $i < 10; $i ++ ) {
    $chains = rand(1, 5);
}
```

**Examples of desired result**

Example one, just one function call

```
$results = $site->filterBy('a_key', 'a_value');
```

Example two, many nested function calls

```
$results = $site->filterBy('a_key', 'a_value')->filterBy('a_key2', 'a_value2')->filterBy('a_key3', 'a_value3')->filterBy('a_key4', 'a_value4')->filterBy('a_key5', 'a_value5')->filterBy('a_key6', 'a_value6');
```

Comment: Can you show an example of desired output with your code ?

Comment: So if i understand it you want to use **filterBy** function many times as you chain value? So if you will have chain 4 you want use filterBy 4 times? an everytime with arguments **"a_key" . ($chain - 1)**?

Comment: Not overly familiar with Kirby but wouldn't it make more sense to just pass an array to `filterBy()` rather than chaining it six times?

Comment: You can't do that with pure functions, but you can with methods, just make sure each call returns `$this`

Comment: @sbeliv01 "Fatal error: Method name must be a string"

Comment: @MatteoTassinari Might be a good answer. Can you write an answer with an example of how it is done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I chain methods in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549423/how-do-i-chain-methods-in-php)

Comment: @JensTörnell I could but it would be a duplicate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$chains = rand(1, 5)
$results = $site
$suffix = ''
for ( $i = 1; $i <= $chains; $i ++) {
    if ($i != 1) {
        $suffix = $i
    }
    $results = $results->filterBy('a_key' . $suffix, 'a_value' . $suffix)
}
```

If you are able to pass `'a_key1'` and `'a_value1'` to the first call to `filterBy` instead of `'a_key'` and `'a_value'`, you could simplify the code by removing `$suffix` and the `if` block and just appending `$i`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to generate the list of chained calls. You can put the arguments of each call in a list then write a new method of the class that gets them from the list and uses them to invoke `filterBy()` repeatedly.

I assume from your example code that function `filterBy()` returns `$this` or another object of the same class as `site`.

```
//
// The code that generates the filtering parameters:

// Store the arguments of the filtering here
$params = array();

// Put as many sets of arguments you need
// use whatever method suits you best to produce them
$params[] = array('key1', 'value1');
$params[] = array('key2', 'value2');
$params[] = array('key3', 'value3');


//
// Do the multiple filtering
$site = new Site();
$result = $site->filterByMultiple($params);


//
// The code that does the actual filtering
class Site {
    public function filterByMultiple(array $params) {
        $result = $this;
        foreach ($params as list($key, $value)) {
            $result = $result->filterBy($key, $value);
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

If `filterBy()` returns `$this` then you don't need the working variable `$result`; call `$this->filterBy()` and `return $this;` and remove the other occurrences of `$result`.